# Modals and Ionic Creator

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic2, invoke

I'm trying to invoke a modal via a button click within Ionic Creator, and seam to be lost. Can someone advice who to get this done? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your attempts so far / some sample code

Comment: you mean ionic creator provided by the official website if so then you are not able to create a project in ionic 2 . you can create only ionic 1 project through ionic creator website

Answer (score 1):

You need to write code for this

First create angular template using html element.
for eg.

```
<script id="templates/modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-modal-view>
        <h3>Modal demo</h3>
    </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

then write code in js file to call the template

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, $ionicModal) {

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
        scope: $scope
      }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });

}
```

and finally add ng-click directive  directive to element.

for eg.

```
<h3 ng-click="modal.show()" >Show modal</h3>
```

Comment: Yes, I can see that. I should have been clearer. How does the code prior to the `<h3 ng-click="modal.show()" >Show modal</h3>` line solve the OP's problem. The answer consists of code with no explanation of what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ionic/ionic_js_modal.htm
Happy Coding. Create the modal on the go, I know is not the best solution but it works!

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $ionicModal) {

       $scope.modal = $ionicModal.fromTemplate( '<ion-modal-view>' +
          ' <ion-header-bar>' +
             '<h1 class = "title">Modal Title</h1>' +
          '</ion-header-bar>' +

          '<ion-content>'+
             '<button class = "button icon icon-left ion-ios-close-outline"
                ng-click = "closeModal()">Close Modal</button>' +
          '</ion-content>' +

       '</ion-modal-view>', {
          scope: $scope,
          animation: 'slide-in-up'
       })

       $scope.openModal = function() {
          $scope.modal.show();
       };

       $scope.closeModal = function() {
          $scope.modal.hide();
       };

       //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
       $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          $scope.modal.remove();
       });

       // Execute action on hide modal
       $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
          // Execute action
       });

       // Execute action on remove modal
       $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
          // Execute action
       });
    });

    //Just invoke it on your click function
    $scope.openModal();
```